# leaflet.js fire event when map pans

Tags: javascript, leaflet, dom-events

I use this function on my backbone view when a new GPS coordinate comes in:

```
onLocationFound: function(position){
    // this function runs every time we get a valid GPS fix
    
    // here I have some preparation code, like getting "position"

    if(myApp.mapView.hasCenter){
      this.map.panTo(position.coords.latlng);
    }
  },
```

Then, on another pice of code I run this function:

```
this.map.on("moveend", function(s){
    that.doDrawReports();
});
```

My Problem is that the `moveend` event isn't catching my `panTo` operation. How can I catch it?

Comment: Are you sure that 'in your other piece of code' `this.map` actually holds the `L.Map` instance? Sounds like a scoping problem

Comment: `this.map` is `L.Map`. I'm sure about that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Could not reproduce your issue sorry:

- With Leaflet 0.7.7: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/186/
- With Leaflet 1.0.0-beta.2: http://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/20/

Test code:

```js
var map = L.map("map").setView([48.86, 2.35], 12);

setInterval(function () {
  var currentPos = map.getCenter();

  map.panTo([
    currentPos.lat,
    currentPos.lng + 0.1
  ])
}, 2000);

map.on("moveend", function () {
  console.log(map.getCenter().toString());
});
```

Even by decreasing the interval down to 50ms, the `moveend` listener is still called.

Comment: I guess the mistake is somewhere else. My code is a bit difficult to test, but this helped to isolate the issue and to prove that `panTo` fires the event `move*`.